# Is there a Zend Tool command for scaffolding?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-tool

Does Zend Tool have a `zf` command that does the same as this Ruby on Rails command:

```
ruby script/generate scaffold ModelName [field:type field:type ...]
```

In other words, can Zend Tool create resources that already contain the code for CRUD actions?

Comment: Can you please give example commands from RoR and/or rephrase the question. The current phrasing is very hard to understand. Are you looking for scaffolding?

Comment: Yeah gordon m looking for scaffolding in ZF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official ZF Command to scaffold.

There are two proposals for this

- http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Controller_Front_Scaffold
- http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Controller_Scaffolding+-+Alex+Oroshchuk

The first one is from 2007 and does not seem to be maintainend any longer. The second one looks like it's more active.

Comment: I had downloaded this http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Controller_Scaffolding+-+Alex+Oroshchuk but not getting how to use the use case 1

Comment: @Rahul sorry, cant help with that.